# Push Data from PLSQL program to Java app

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

We usually query the DB using JDBC and get the data we want to display but I wish to push data from my PLSQL program to Java desktop application. Is there any standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For simple notifications you could use the `DBMS_ALERT` package within your `PL/SQL` code. For more complex situations you could investigate the use of [Oracle AQ](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm) and JMS or [Oracle Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28321/strms_over.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the leads. I will explore these.